# compiling software for embedded linux distro (openwrt)

Tags: linux, compilation, embedded, openwrt

I have a problem with Linux embedded OpenWRT.
I must compile a software for arch MIPS.
The software is composed of 2 file.c and 4 /include/file.h ... 
I have compiled a toolchain for Openwrt with the "new" gcc (for mips) I have compiled one by one the 2 file.c getting 2 file.o as output. How can I create a unique binary file to execute the software?

Second question: it is correct to compile the file one by one?

Thanks, I hope that my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an OpenWrt package. See this [tutorial](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages). You can [point](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+YegorYefremov/posts/ANTkC9Ysv25) OpenWrt to the folder, where your files are and let compile the project there instead of pulling it from a VCS repo.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18777608/1113139) about compiling multiple files with GCC.