# How to use functions in a package that is written in C in a different location

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to use a linear algebra package called [hnfprof](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eastorjoh/hnfproj.html). I have done the installation with the given instructions and now its ready to use. Now I want to use some functions in hnfproj/src/lift/lift.c file. I want to create my own matrix examples and check outputs for each functions separately. I am not clear how to do this. (I know only basics of C language, creating .c files in a folder and running it in my Ubuntu terminal.)
I know that I should write a C file including this "#include <lift.c>" file name and creating a matrix in my file "main.c". I don't know how to include a file name in a different location. When I compile I can not use "gcc -o program main.c lift.c".  My "main.c" file is in a different folder. I don't want to create any make file inside the package folder. So how I can just use the "lift.c" file inside my "main.c" file which is in a separate folder "Main"  and create all executable make files inside "Main" folder?

If its difficult to give a answer, appreciate if you can suggest me some source to learn this. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622409/how-to-link-multiple-implementation-files-in-c

Comment: I have two files in two different locations

Answer (score 0):

No need to include `lift.c` directly in `main.c`, and you can call function in `lift.c` from main.

When it comes to compilation, you can use:

```
gcc -o program main.c file_location/lift.c
```

If you need other options, add them (most flags at the start; libraries at the end, after the source code). You can also compile each file to object code separately and then link the object files together:

```
  gcc -c main.c
  gcc -c file_location/lift.c
  gcc -o program main.o lift.o
```

refer

> [Compiling multiple C files with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777326/compiling-multiple-c-files-with-gcc)